# Related to reports

Tags: reporting, administration

On opportunity there is a amount field. when we run report on this in the report instead of 11000 is it possible to display Amount  as 11k.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options here:

1. Try using a dashboard as it should then display using K, M, etc.
2. Add a formula field on opportunity that displays the value as text (you can divide by 1000, see if greater than 1 and then if so output with k, otherwise leave)
3. If using a summary report you can add a formula in the summary report that will do the same as above.

Note that options 2 and 3 won't allow display on a graph as 11k.